# Class imported from two different paths is not equal?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

It seems that entities imported using two different `PYTHONPATH`s are *not* the same objects.

I have encouneted a little problem in my code and I want to explain it with a little testcase.

I created the source tree:

```
a/
  __init__.py
  b/
    __init__.py
    example.py
```

in example.py:

```
class Example:
  pass
```

and from the parent of folder `a`, I run python and this test:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/marco/temp/a")
>>> 
>>> import a.b.example as example1
>>> import b.example as example2
>>> 
>>> example1.Example is example2.Example
False
```

So the question is: why the result is `False`? Even if imported by two different paths, the class is the same. This is a complete mess if the class is a custom exception and you try to catch it with `except`.

Tested with python 3.4.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python the `class` statement is an executable statement, so each time you execute it you will create a new class.

When you import a module Python will check `sys.modules` to see whether a module at the specified path already exists. If it does then you will just get back the same module, if not it will try to load the module and execute the code it contains.

So two different paths to the same module will load the code twice, which executes the `class` statement twice and you get two independent classes defined.

This usually hits people when they have a file `a.py` which they run as a script and then in another module attempt to import `a`. The script is loaded as `__main__` so has different classes and different global variables than the imported module.

The moral is, always be consistent in how you reference a module.

Comment: `When you import a module Python will check sys.modules to see whether a module at the specified path already exists` The problem is the real module path is the same indeed, it's the `PYTHONPATH` that differs. Since I'm using python3 that disallows `..` imports, I think the real path could and should be checked instead.

Comment: Not the file path, the module path, i.e. the name of the module which here is `a.b.example` or `b.example`. Two different names, two different modules.

Comment: Regarding "not the module path": It is possible (in python3.6) that str(class1) == str(class2), but class1 != class2.   
str(classX) seems to show the module path, it looks like this:  '<class \'my_package1.sub_package2.file1.MyClass\'>'

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator is used to check if two names are pointing to the same object (memory location).

```
example1.Example is example2.Example
```

are obviously not pointing at the same locations since you are importing the same object two times.

But, if you did something like:

```
a, b = example1.Example, example1.Example

a is b # True
```

Instead, you should use the `==` operator:

```
example1.Example == example2.Example
True
```

Note that if you don't implement `__eq__`or `__hash__`, the default behavior is the same as `is`

Comment: Have you tried that? Equality comparison for the two classes will return `False` even if their definitions are identical. For a class `==` is usually exactly the same as `is` (though I guess you could override the behaviour with a metaclass but that would be unusual).

Comment: @Duncan Yes, if you don't implement `__eq__`or `__hash__ `The default behavior is the same as is

Comment: @Duncan If that was always the case, since everything is an object in python, `==` would works for nothing.

Comment: No, is you define `__eq__` on a class then you have redefined comparison for the instances of that class. Lots of classes do that. To redefine comparison for the class itself you have to define `__eq__` on the metaclass. That is pretty unusual (any use of metaclasses is fairly unusual).